# What is WindowsApp folder for?

Tags: windows

I found there are tons of folders (took around 6GB) in `C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApp` that looks like its useless while one of my friends asked me to help to delete some kind of s2pid apps that installed on his laptop and the apps folder was inside `C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApp` as well. (he claimed that he didnt install by himself, perhaps he didnt realized but it doesnt matter anymore because I have done the delete).

I am so curious to know what is the `C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApp` for and is it safe to delete all the folder in it ?

Comment: They are all the Windows Apps you have installed. Windows Apps are a particular type of app. Not normal Windows' programs. These are newer programs like Mail, Weather, and Calculator. Also ANY program downloaded from the Windows Store - apart from a few preinstalled Windows Apps in Windows all other Windows Apps come from the Windows Store.

Comment: So is it normal when others than the Windows Apps installed and located the folder in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApp for

A short explanation of what the folder does is stated [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-windows-apps-hidden-folder-and-why-cant-i/40a60508-c409-422a-af92-bd51fe5a4ca9):

> WindowsApp folder is where modern apps sandboxed from everything in the system which makes them rather secure compared to other desktop programs.

> is it safe to delete all the folder in it ?

You can delete it but you have to be certain that there are no modern apps installed as stated [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/delete-the-windowsapps-folder-on-windows-10/):

> The WindowsApps folder is where UWP apps are installed. UWP apps can be installed or moved to any drive on your system. What this means is that if you’ve ever installed an app to a non-Windows drive, it will have the WindowsApps folder. As such, if you want to delete the WindowsApps folder from a drive, you have to make sure that there is no UWP app installed to the drive the folder is on.